# How do I fetch all comments per post via WP REST API?

Tags: php, functions, javascript, comments, rest-api

I am busy trying to understand how WP REST API works in combination with React. When I check the documentation of WP REST API, it confuses me a bit.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#retrieve-a-comment

For example here, it seems like you have to specifically give the ID of a post in the query to fetch the post. Can we not use a variable for this? If so, how could this be done? And how could we make sure that per post, automatically we also fetch its comments beneath it?

I mean, this gets all of the comments:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments
```

But it does not let me combine this with the posts. How do we relate them with each other?

Another example:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=33
```

Would mean that we you fetch the categories of post with ID = 33, but how can we make this generic? Like `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=$GET_POST_ID` or so?

Comment: That logic belongs in our application. Your app should know which post is displaying and you can use that to request comments for that post by specifying the ID. The rest API is stateless, you need to tell it what you want. It can’t figure that out for you.

Comment: Yes, but how on earth? I mean, the documentation is incredibly poor (or I just don't get it). Can you help a bit more?

Comment: It's documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#list-comments You just need to specify the `post` argument to limit comments to the specified post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=<POST_ID>
```

will return comments for a specific post